# Angular Routing - disabling scrollPositionRestoration for certain routes or modules

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an Angular app with quite a few lazy-loaded modules. I'm using `scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'` on my AppRoutingModule and everything is working as expected.

```
// app-routing.module.ts

...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            initialNavigation: 'enabled',
            scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
        }),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

However, I have one lazy-loaded module (FilterModule) which is basically a filter page for the products and based on the combination of filters selected, the routes change (adding / removing `queryParams`) which fires a route change event and the page is scrolled to top (as expected).

But I would like to *disable* the `scrollPositionRestoration` "effect" particularly on this module and its routes. Is there an angular way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the scroll using your own logic inside the AppComponent.

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
// app-routing.module.ts

...
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], // scrollPositionRestoration managed inside AppComponent for custom logic
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```
// app.component.ts

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly viewportScroller: ViewportScroller
  ) {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event): event is Scroll => event instanceof Scroll),
      pairwise()
    ).subscribe(events => {
      const prevUrl = events[0].routerEvent.url.split('?')[0];
      const currentUrl = events[1].routerEvent.url.split('?')[0];
      if (prevUrl !== currentUrl) {
        // Scroll top only if previous url is different from current
        // This prevents the scroll on query param update in the same page
        this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```